# Usage of Types.NULL in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am wondering about the intended usage of the [Types.NULL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#NULL)  constant in the JDBC. I am guessing from the javadoc that a literal value in a SQL statement can have the type Types.NULL.

For example, the null literal in this statement, could have the type Types.NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM integer_table WHERE integer_column = null
```

I have also seen examples where the null literal is assigned the type Types.CHAR and then changed to Types.Integer when the type of integer_column is discovered by the SQL processor. Are both approaches correct? Is one more correct than the other?

I am also guessing that you cannot have a column that is the type Types.NULL because it is not a 'SQL Type'. Is this correct?

Are there any other usages?

NOTE: I am aware of how null comparisons behave in SQL, but this is just an example and is not relevant to my question.

Comment: I have used the Types.NULL type when setting parameters on PreparedStatements which have null as a value, regardless of the columns actual db type.  As for SQL having a null type, I think your right with it not being a SQL Type, its the absence of the type. As you have seen for yourself, a null never equals anything, even another null. For what its worth, I have grown fond of using the PreparedStatement.setObject(index, Types.OTHER) for sets on PreparedStatements. This function just lets the jbdc driver (I dont know if others function this way) auto resolve the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a query which has `? IS NULL` as the condition, the parameter can be described as a `NULL`-type, and in that case the JDBC driver can report it as a `Types.NULL`.

With regard to NULL SQL:2011 says:

> Every data type includes a special value, called the null value, sometimes denoted by the keyword NULL. This value differs from other values in the following respects:
>
> - Since the null value is in every data type, the data type of the null value implied by the keyword NULL cannot be inferred; hence NULL can be used to denote the null value only in certain contexts, rather than everywhere that a literal is permitted.

So the NULL type is not really a type, but all types at once, on the other hand given my example (a parameter in an `? IS NULL`), you need something to indicate that the value can be anything that is null or not null.

This for example is the case for Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver); disclosure: I am one of the Jaybird developers. When a parameter is of type `NULL`, a call to any `setXXX` with any value will make that parameter not null except for a value of `null` (or a call to `setNull()`) . Also some (most?) drivers will allow a call to `setNull()` with the specific sql type and also with `Types.NULL`.

Comment: Great answer - thanks! A call to setNull(..) should never make the parameter not null though?

Comment: Hmm, I may need to rephrase that "other than `null` (or a call to setNull()`" is the entire exception ;)